# Rendering android frame buffer data to compressed image format

Tags: android, image

Need help in converting raw image data to a well known compressed format like png or jpg.
I am using the '/dev/graphics/fb0' to get the frame buffer for an android phone and I am saving the raw data to a local file say 'image.raw'.

Now is there any good tool or code that can process the raw file and generate compressed images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the framebuffer capture and PNG compression done in the old AOSP `screenshot` command.  Source is [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/kitkat-release/cmds/screenshot/screenshot.c).  It's just using libpng.

The framebuffer device doesn't work on many newer devices.  You have to ask the system compositor for a copy of the screen.  See the [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/kitkat-release/cmds/screencap/screencap.cpp) for the `screencap` command to see how that's done.  (Note it falls back to fbdev if it can't contact SurfaceFlinger.)  That command uses Skia's interface to libpng to compress with PNG if requested (`-p` flag).